Socket IO server does not receive signals
I am trying to connect to a socket.io server being hosted at render.com
My next app is supposed to connect to it from its own vercel deployment
However even thought both parts are active and successfuly deployed. I get no information transmition...
I do get "Socket server listening on port 5000"
Here is my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const { createServer } = require('http');


const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*', 
      methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A client connected'); // This does not log

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('A client disconnected');
    });
});

httpServer.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Socket server listening on port 5000'); // This logs
});

And here is the code from next.js which is supposed to create the connection:
import io from 'socket.io-client';
...
  useEffect(() => {
    const serverUrl = "https://myrenderdotcomurl.com:5000";
    const socket = io(serverUrl); // tried {transports: ['websocket']} as second paramter already

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to socket.io server'); // This does not log
    });

    return () => { socket.disconnect() };
  }, []);

...

Lastly, the error on client console
WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' failed:

Thanks from the start
